# Ruby regex that splits on newline, space, or comma

Tags: ruby, regex

Input:

```
     f = ["happy days",
         "happy\ndays",
         "happy,days",
         "happy, days"]

     patt = /some_regex/
```

My desired output after splitting each string in `f` on `patt` is ["happy", "days"].

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try this as your pattern:

```
/\W+/
```

It matches any number of non-word characters.

Example code:

```
result = f.map{|s| s.split(/\W+/) }
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/x75kq)

Answer (score 7):

Or `/[\n ,]+/`

Comment: /[\r\n ,]+/ Worked great for me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
f.map{ |s| s.split /[,\s]+/}

=> [["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array, using String#scan looking for words:

```
f = [
  "happy days",
  "happy\ndays",
  "happy,days",
  "happy, days"
]

require 'pp'
pp f.map{ |s| s.scan(/\w+/) }

>> [["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"], ["happy", "days"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):242:0> "a\nb".split(/\n/)
[
    [0] "a",
    [1] "b"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split on "comma with space" or "newline" then try this

> "your string".replace(/^\s+$/mg, '\n').replace(/(,\s)|\n+/gm,
>   '~').split('~')

basically this particular regex will help

> /(,\s)|\n+/gm